# debounce is not working with keyup event in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a `text box` to enter some text to search records. I am using `data-ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"` with `keyup` event, `data-ng-model-options"` working fine, but I want to fire `keyup` event after the `debounce` time duration.
Currently `keyup` event fires instantly before `debounce duration`. May be I doing something wrong.

Here is my `HTML`

```
<input type="text" id="focusOnMe" placeholder="Search..."/ data-ng-keyup="loadSearchResult($event)" data-ng-model="searchText" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }">
```

And this is my `Keyup event` action

```
$scope.loadSearchResult = function(event) {
  $rootScope.hideSearchResult = true;
  $rootScope.showLoading = true;
  var searchText = $scope.searchText.trim();
  if (searchText.length > 0) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/secure/search',
      data: {
        searchText: searchText,
        peopleFlag: checkboxValueForPeopleSearch,
        colonyFlag: checkboxValueForColonySearch
      }
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data !== undefined || data !== null) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.hideSearchResult = false;
          $rootScope.showLoading = false;

          $scope.allSearchResult = {
            "bookmarks": data.bookmarks,
            "people": data.people,
            "colonies": data.colonies
          };
        }, 300);
      } else {
        $rootScope.showLoading = false;
        commonNotification($rootScope, false, true, true, 'something went wrong!');
        $timeout(function() {
          $rootScope.newStatus = false;

        }, 2000);
      }

    }).error(function(err) {

    });
  } else {
    $rootScope.hideSearchResult = true;
    $rootScope.showLoading = false;
  }

};
```

Sorry the code is dependent to more files, so that I don't have `plunker` example

Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

*Thank You*

Answer (score 4):

Debounce doesn't affect the keyup event. It only delays the assigning of the model ($scope) variable. So your keyup event fires immediately and loadSearchResult runs before you want it to.

To solve it, you can add a watch tied to $scope.searchText.

```
$scope.$watch('searchText', function (newValue) {
  loadSearchResult(newValue);
});
```

Super-simple and cleanly-coded because we're using the [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) ($scope).

Note: I omitted the event object because you're not using it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you specify debounce in ng-model-options, it will change the way model gets updated. But it won't change how key event works. For your case, use _.debounce would help:

`var delay = 500;
$scope.loadSearchResult = _.debounce($scope.loadSearchResult, delay);`

Comment: For those who aren't familiar, this requires lodash (the _ object): https://lodash.com/