# Adding debounce to an input text box with an "ng-keyup" in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debouncing

I have this directive for a search box

```js
// Define the search-box
alSH.directive('searchBox',[function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
          template: `
    <input 
      placeholder="Search.." 
      class="search-box"
      ng-keyup=search($evt) 
      ng-model="query"
      ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
    />`,
        controller: function SearchBoxController($scope, helper) {
    $scope.query = ''; //ng model
    $scope.search = function() { //this calls in every keyup event
      helper.setQuery($scope.query).search();
    };
    
    helper.setQuery('').search();
  }
    };
}]);
```

and i tried to use `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"` but still it keeps sending a network request for each key stroke without updating the `ng-model` probably due to the `ng-keyup`.
I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186657/debounce-is-not-working-with-keyup-event-in-angular) which asks for something similar but I didn't seem to understand the solution

I have added a [codepen](https://codepen.io/cmgchess/pen/MWrZdOq) demo which has the above code snippet where I'm trying to achieve this behavior

Ideally I would like to limit the number of backend calls sent due to each key stroke. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [debounce is not working with keyup event in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186657/debounce-is-not-working-with-keyup-event-in-angular)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner i saw that post before but i'm not sure how to add it to the mine. where to change and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing with an [answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154942/13583510) I managed to add the debouncing.
I removed the **`ng-keyup=search($evt)`** but kept the **`ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"`**.

```html
    <input 
      placeholder="Search.." 
      class="search-box"
      ng-model="query"
      ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
    />
```

Then in the controller added a watcher which keeps track of the `$scope.query` variable which triggers the search function. To keep it simple i didn't use the values of `newValue` and `oldValue` but extra functionality can be achieved using those as well if needed. [solved codepen](https://codepen.io/cmgchess/pen/MWrxVQR)

```js
          $scope.$watch('query', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.search();
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a simmilar pattern:

```
var debounceTimer = false;
$scope.search= function() {
    // if there's already a timeout going, cancel the current one
    if (debounceTimer) {
        $timeout.cancel(debounceTimer);
    }
    // create a new timeout, do your thing when it ellapses
    debounceTimer = $timeout(function() { 
        // ... your action goes here, only if calls are made with at least ONE second interval ...  
        helper.setQuery($scope.query).search();        
    },
    // adjust your time interval accordingly 
    1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use `ng-change` instead of `ng-keyup`.

Long answer:

Usually using ng-keyup is just wrong as there are lots of ways input value can be modified (e.g. drag-drop), also some keys will not modify input value, e.g. Esc key. Thats why u should be always careful with just using keyup and better use input change events.

If you use ng-model you should require ngModel directive, inject and use ngModelCtrl. That's what ng-change is doing for you: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9bff2ce8fb170d7a33d3ad551922d7e23e9f82fc/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js

In simple scenarios you dont need to know all that and you can stick to `ng-change` + `ng-model-options`, for very specific cases with some weird debounce/throttle/whatever logic when built-in possibilities are not enough, you write custom e.g. `my-change` directive which works similar way.